# Module variable doesn't keep its state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module in Ruby containing one method and one variable:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  @var1 = MyModel::CONST1.each_with_index.map { |item, i| [item, i] }
  def method1 v1, v2, v3 = @var1[0]
    #....
    # access to @var1
  end
end
```

The reason I want `@var1` to be a variable is that if it was a method it would be evaluated each I access to it within `method1`. It's not reasonable and thus, I want it to be evaluated only once.

However, when I call this `method1` (it's a helper method) via ajax (ajax-based dialog which uses it), @var1 turns out to be nil. Likewise, during a first page loading it's filled out as I expect.

What do I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context is not the same (see):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  p self # => ApplicationHelper

  def method1
    p self # => #<OtherClass:0x007fbe032cf6f0> an instance of an object
  end
end
```

Ruby doesn't work like Java in the sense that you aren't able to set object instance variables in the context of a module (or class) as you did. In your code, `@var1 = MyModel::CONST1.each_with_index.map { |item, i| [item, i] }` is defining an instance variable `var1` on the actual module object `ApplicationHelper`, **not** on any instance.

In Ruby, when you only want to define a variable once, we use the `||=` memoization trick:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def method1
    @var1 ||= MyModel::CONST1.each_with_index.map { |item, i| [item, i] }
  end
end
```

This is a trick that leverages the fact that the first time you reference a variable it will be `nil` and `nil` is considered fasely in Ruby. So the above line is the shortcut for writing:

```
@var1 || @var1 = MyModel::CONST1.each_with_index.map { |item, i| [item, i] }
```

**NOTE:** Be aware that if `@var1` could be the values `nil` or `false` this will re-evaluate it each time. However, in this case. Since you are using [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) you will get `[]`, and not `nil`, if there are no items. So the usage will be as expected in this situation.

This has an issue with the edge case the first time you call `method1` because you are using it to set a default value. If we instead use message passing instead of direct variable access, we can achieve what you are looking for:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def method1(v1, v2, v3 = var1.first)
    #....
    # all further access to @var1 is done by passing the message var1
    tmp = var1.select{ ... }
  end

  def var1
    @var1 ||= MyModel::CONST1.each_with_index.map { |item, i| [item, i] }
  end
end
```